# How to make qml round buttons same size in row layout

Tags: qml

I have the following code that displays a row of buttons.
I want to have the buttons have the same width but dont seem to be able to get there.
Anybody know how to do this?

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {

        RowLayout {
            id: rowLayout
            RoundButton {
                id: roundButton
                text: "Engage"
            }

            RoundButton {
                id: roundButton1
                text: "Disengage"
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ehmm ... `Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width / 2`? That provided, of course, that you will set some size for `RowLayout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the trick. Make shure `RoundButton` **doesn't** set its `width` and `height` properties, but uses `implicitWidth` and `implicitHeight` so it uses the size of the Layout.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {

        RowLayout {
            id: rowLayout
            width: parent.width
            height: 300
            RoundButton {
                id: roundButton
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                text: "Engage"
            }

            RoundButton {
                id: roundButton1
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                text: "Disengage"
            }
        }
    }
}
```